# Need to find a web database of german words for taboo game

Tags: databases

I am looking for a web database of german words like [this](http://taboogame.net/?) in english. Anyone knows sth about this? I develop the game based on such database of words, so this is why I asked about this here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to game development.

Comment: Just because you're making a game and encountered this problem doesn't make this question on-topic here (see the [help]). Even if it *did*, we also don't consider questions that are effectively asking for lists or resources or where to find resources on-topic in any event.

Comment: Please tell me what is apriopriate forum on stack exchange to ask this question.

Comment: If there is a german language stack exchange, I would suggest you ask on their _chat_, not on their site. Asking for lists tends to be off topic for most SE sites.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Lexical_databases lists articles describing a multitude of lexical databases for a multitude of languages, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GermaNet. This might be overkill for a taboo-like game though.